# When placing coloured patches in the UI how can I assign increasing numbers to the patches depending on the order of placement?

Tags: netlogo

I currently have a program where you can draw coloured patches in the UI from which turtles spawn.

The turtles that have spawned then follow routes that the user draws out to another patch type where they then cease to exist.

What I want to is to be able to distinguish the coloured patches (the patches where the turtles spawn) from one another by assigning a number to each patch that increases incrementally depending of the order of the placement of the patch in the UI.

How do I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing, but see if this is useful.

```
globals [n-colored]

to-color [#patch #pcolor]
  ask #patch [
    set pcolor #pcolor
    set n-colored (n-colored + 1)
    set plabel (word n-colored)
  ]
end
```

Each colored patch's `plabel` now distinguishes it, which seems to be what you are after.  (If you already use `plabel` for something else, just add an appropriate patch attribute.)

Comment: `set plabel n-colored` works fine too, no real need for explicit conversion to string.

Comment: should I replace #color with the colour of the desired patch I wish to create attributes for?

Comment: The `to-color` procedure has two input arguments, `#patch` and `#pcolor`.  So you call it like `to-color mypatch red` in order to color the patch `mypatch` red. (Was that your question?)

Comment: The patches have already been drawn. Does your code allow for the drawing of patches of certain colours , then storing the number, or just storing the number of patch that has been drawn by another piece of code?

Comment: What do you mean "the patches have already been drawn"?  Your question states: "What I want to is to be able to distinguish the coloured patches (the patches where the turtles spawn) from one another by assigning a number to each patch that increases incrementally depending of the order of the placement of the patch in the UI."  This suggests that you want to number them as you color them.  (How else will you know the "order of the placement"?)                                                       (By the way, the patches already exist and are not "placed"; you are just changing the pcolor.)